# Unknown distribution format: '' when uploading to PyPI via Twine

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I am trying to update the version of `infixpy` using `twine`. Here is my `~/.pypirc`:

```
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ 
username: myuser
password: mypassword

[pypitest]
repository: https://upload.testpypi.org/legacy
username: myuser
password: mypassword
```

Here is the command line:

```
python setup.py build
twine upload -r  pypi dist/
```

The upload errors out with  `InvalidDistribution: Unknown distribution format: ''`

Here is the full output:

```
Processing dependencies for infixpy==0.0.6
Finished processing dependencies for infixpy==0.0.6
Processing /Users/steve/git/infixpy
Building wheels for collected packages: infixpy
  Building wheel for infixpy (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for infixpy: filename=infixpy-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl size=43459 sha256=01fed46f42fa86475079636a55685c93521989aa0ba6558726a9d35c01004b7a
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/d6/m67jyndd7h754m3810cl3bpm0000gp/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-1bizg6_y/wheels/47/66/74/d79a56979feba04c8ef05e12fe861cacf813cecd397e57071f
Successfully built infixpy
Installing collected packages: infixpy
  Attempting uninstall: infixpy
    Found existing installation: infixpy 0.0.6
    Uninstalling infixpy-0.0.6:
      Successfully uninstalled infixpy-0.0.6
Successfully installed infixpy-0.0.6
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
InvalidDistribution: Unknown distribution format: ''
```

What corrections are needed to my publishing process? I am on Python 3.7 on macOS.

Comment: It expects a *file*; `dist/` is a *directory*, so you're ending up at https://github.com/pypa/twine/blob/668f4db44d2965d9009308d96e13776069d050db/twine/package.py#L88-L90

Comment: Huh. I had used this approach in the past: in fact I ran it from a custom install script used successfully. Maybe the twine publishing changed? oh - i missed the "*" after "/dist"

Comment: I changed it to reference an `.egg` and it does work. You can make it an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://twine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#twine-upload) for `twine upload` (emphasis mine):

```
positional arguments:
  dist                  The distribution files to upload to the repository
                        (package index). Usually dist/* . May additionally
                        contain a .asc file to include an existing signature
                        with the file upload.
```

You've passed a *directory*, not *files* - as the docs suggest, you probably want `dist/*`. If you pass a directory there are no matches for known distributions, as these are based on file extension, so you end up at [this error case](https://github.com/pypa/twine/blob/668f4db44d2965d9009308d96e13776069d050db/twine/package.py#L87-L90):

```
        else:
            raise exceptions.InvalidDistribution(
                "Unknown distribution format: '%s'" % os.path.basename(filename)
            )
```

The [`basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) for a directory is `''`, hence the not-so-helpful output.

Answer (score 5):

add * after dist/ like this : `twine upload -r  pypi dist/*`

#### But Why?

Because dist/ is a directory and it expects a file to be uploaded, not any directory.
So, the files will be **all(*)** files inside dist folder